# identify content type of silverlight url

Tags: c#, silverlight

following url is input to my c# code:

```
"https://xxxx/sss/ddd/dd/ui/resity/I/Rme/StartPage.html?app.component=/SCT/an/root.uiccwoc&rootWindow=X&redirectUrl=/sp/public/byd/runtime";
```

it downloads a silverlight app and runs it. i need to identify when it starts downloading xap file.

Could anyone suggest code sample.

Comment: What platform are you downloading the Silverlight app to? That is, is your C# code running in WinForms, WPF, ASP.NET? What mechanism (C# class) are you using to download the xap data?

Comment: @chris:i want it implemented in winforms.

Comment: @chris: I am a beginner. This is my first project. I am first trying to resolve the input url, so that i can get the response header with content - type : "application/x-silverlight"

Comment: Consider using the `WebClient` class. It has many convenience methods to download data from the Internet, including events that notify the transfer progress. Consider using its `DownloadDataAsync` (or `DownloadFileAsync` if you want to save to the file system automatically) and leverage its `DownloadProgressChanged` event.